# Value of c:when test in jsp is not recognized

Tags: java, jsp

this is my code, but always is evaluate clause otherwise

```
var typeA= entity.type;

alert(typeA);
$(".scrollLoading")
    .append(
        "<div class='panel panel-default'>"
        + "<div class='panel-heading'> <h4 class='panel-title text'> <a style='text-decoration: none'   class='accordion-toggle collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion' href='#collapse"
        + id
        + "' onclick='selectActivityForProspect("
        + id
        + ")'> "
        +"<c:choose>  <c:when test='${"+typeA+" eq \'EMAIL\'}'> <img src='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/email.png' width='16' height='16'/>" 
        + "</c:when> <c:when test='${"+typeA+" == CALL}'> <img src='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/call.png' width='16' height='16'/>" 
        + " </c:when> <c:otherwise> <img src='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/campaign.png' width='16' height='16'/>"
        + " </c:otherwise></c:choose>&nbsp;&nbsp; "
```

var typeA is not recognized. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: you should to refactor your code, it is not clear!

Comment: Are you writing JSP in a JQuery append code ? Don't, JSP is interpreted on the server (tomcat, glassfish, ...). Once it is received by the client (IE, Chrome, Firefox, ...), the JSP is no longer usable, every JSP tags as been read and replace by his results. The client CAN NOT read jsp.

Comment: yes but for example method onclick() is recognized... it is not possible also for c:when test?

Comment: Server code != Client code, you are completely lost.

Comment: You don't understand, onclick is a `javascript` function, this run on the webclient (your browser). but `<c:when></c:when>` is a `jsp` tag, those are read and understand ONLY on your server. It is why you need to put your jsp file on this server and not a simple web server. Once the file leave the server, there is no `jsp` tags anymore, everything is HTML/Javascript/CSS (an any other langage that I can't think of). You need to update your code to use JQuery (Javascript) to do the logic, or you are going to need to call a other jsp (with your tags) in ajax to get the result (complicated ;) )

Comment: ok...thanks i resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this deserve an answer to put you on the right tracks.

You are not understanding the difference between the server and client part.

JSP is a server code, it is run ONLY on the server. The client (browser) can't understand it. 
Every tags in `jsp` will be decoded and replace by the output (the value of c:out/ the value between a specific tag condition/...).

The client part (on the browser) can't understand the `jsp` but is know `javascript`. This is why you can use JQuery (written in Javascript).

This is the same for every server langage (PHP, ASP, ...), you write it for the server to be understand by the server. The client will NEVER receive anything in those langage.

Comment: please, be free to give me advise on some point to clarify. I will make a documentation on this problem later